# FROM UNIX TIME in Presto syntax

Tags: sql, unix, casting, presto

I'm currently trying to collect data that falls between 2 dates via Unix timestamp. All of our dates are stored as VARCHARs to the CAST function is used.

The line in my query reads as:

```
FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '%Y %D %M %h:%i:%s %x') between 
CAST(d.start_date AS TIMESTAMP) and CAST(d.end_date AS TIMESTAMP)
```

This returns as error:

> Function unix_timestamp not registered

I also tried:

```
CAST(from_unixtime(unixtime) AS DATE) between 
CAST(start_date AS DATE) and CAST(end_date AS DATE)
```

This produces the error:

> Column `unixtime` cannot be resolved

Any suggestions?

Comment: unix_timestamp is a hive function, not a presto function.  If you happen to be working with an internal team/fork, support can be added for unix_timestamp and other similar functions.  I think starburst and presto-sql community forks are generally working towards hive support anyway, but I'm not sure how complete it is (I see it in v330 for presto-sql).  We recently added an overload for this unix_timestamp function to our internal presto - some notes here - https://coding-stream-of-consciousness.com/2020/02/29/add-a-new-sql-function-to-presto-support-unix_timestamp-from-hive/.

Answer (score 3):

Presto does not support `unix_timestamp()` function. You need to convert your `varchar` to `date`.

So:

```
now() BETWEEN
date_parse(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AND
date_parse(end_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
```

Adjust the date format string as per scenario.

For a full list of Presto date and time function, refer to: https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html

Answer (score -1):

I've used the code below to convert a unix timestamp to a date. You should then be able to compare it to the other two dates.

```
CAST(from_unixtime(unix_ts_col) AS DATE)
```

In the database I use, the unix timestamp has been stored as a string, so I had to cast it to an integer first.

```
CAST(from_unixtime(CAST(unix_ts_col AS INTEGER)) AS DATE);
```